# How to preg_match_all() + extract + replace + delete?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all, str-replace

I'm not very experienced with preg_match_all and similar and am looking for a simple way to do the following:

Consider this text:

```
$string = 'This text was written on [set_stamp]1341066037[/set_stamp] and this one on [set_stamp]1340903119[/set_stamp].';
```

What I need to do:

1. Get data (here timestamps) between ALL tags `[set_stamp]` and `[/set_stamp]`
2. Replace all captured timestamps with their corresponding date like: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)`
3. Remove all `[set_stamp]` and `[/set_stamp]` tags

The final output would be something similar to this:

> "This text was written on 2012-07-12 14:26 and this one on 2012-07-11 17:10."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback()` with the following regex:

```
#\[set_stamp\](.+)\[/set_stamp\]#iU
```

Example code:

```
$string = 'This text was written on [set_stamp]1341066037[/set_stamp] and this one on [set_stamp]1340903119[/set_stamp].';
echo preg_replace_callback('#\[set_stamp\](.+)\[/set_stamp\]#iU', function($m) {
    return date('Y-m-d H:i', $m[1]);
}, $string);
```

The output of that code is:

> This text was written on 2012-06-30 16:20 and this one on 2012-06-28 19:05.

Note that the anonymous function requires at least PHP 5.3. If you are using an old version and really can't update, simply create a normal function and pass its name as a string.